# SQL Query to convert XML Data to Columns in Table

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a table in my database which has a column of data type `xml(.)`
I want to extract the elements of that column and and flatten it to a table.

[image]

This is how the XML page looks like:

```
<xsd:ArrayOfControl xmlns:xsd="http://tempuri.org/FormPersistance.xsd">
  <xsd:Control>
    <xsd:N>pg1_UIObject1</xsd:N>
    <xsd:V />
    <xsd:T>StlAnnotationControl</xsd:T>
    <xsd:A />
  </xsd:Control>
  <xsd:Control>
    <xsd:N>pg1_TabItem1Panel1</xsd:N>
    <xsd:V />
    <xsd:T>StlCanvas</xsd:T>
    <xsd:A />
  </xsd:Control>
  <xsd:Control>
    <xsd:N>pg1_txtPrefix</xsd:N>
    <xsd:V>MS</xsd:V>
    <xsd:T>StlTextBox</xsd:T>
    <xsd:A />
  </xsd:Control>
  <xsd:Control>
    <xsd:N>pg1_txtSurname</xsd:N>
    <xsd:V>Joey</xsd:V>
    <xsd:T>StlTextBox</xsd:T>
    <xsd:A />
  </xsd:Control>
  <xsd:Control>
    <xsd:N>pg1_txtNO</xsd:N>
    <xsd:V>400232</xsd:V>
    <xsd:T>StlTextBox</xsd:T>
    <xsd:A />
  </xsd:Control>
</xsd:ArrayOfControl>
```

Below is the code I am using to flatten it:

```
SELECT e.page_id, e.entry_id, 
   cast(e.page_xml as xml).value('(/ArrayofControl/Control/N)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS Col,
   cast(e.page_xml as xml).value('(/ArrayofControl/Control/V)[1]', 'varchar(250)') AS Col1,
   cast(e.page_xml as xml).value('(/ArrayofControl/Control/T)[1]', 'varchar(250)') AS Col2,
   cast(e.page_xml as xml).value('(/ArrayofControl/Control/A)[1]', 'varchar(250)') AS Col3
FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[Form] e
```

Upon running the above code, I get null values for col, col1,col2,col3. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It is a minimal reproducible example. Just copy it as-is to SSMS and run it.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (page_id INT, entry_id INT, page_xml XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (page_id, entry_id, page_xml) VALUES
(2219, 1996, N'<xsd:ArrayOfControl xmlns:xsd="http://tempuri.org/FormPersistance.xsd">
  <xsd:Control>
    <xsd:N>pg1_UIObject1</xsd:N>
    <xsd:V />
    <xsd:T>StlAnnotationControl</xsd:T>
    <xsd:A />
  </xsd:Control>
  <xsd:Control>
    <xsd:N>pg1_TabItem1Panel1</xsd:N>
    <xsd:V />
    <xsd:T>StlCanvas</xsd:T>
    <xsd:A />
  </xsd:Control>
  <xsd:Control>
    <xsd:N>pg1_txtPrefix</xsd:N>
    <xsd:V>MS</xsd:V>
    <xsd:T>StlTextBox</xsd:T>
    <xsd:A />
  </xsd:Control>
  <xsd:Control>
    <xsd:N>pg1_txtSurname</xsd:N>
    <xsd:V>Joey</xsd:V>
    <xsd:T>StlTextBox</xsd:T>
    <xsd:A />
  </xsd:Control>
  <xsd:Control>
    <xsd:N>pg1_txtNO</xsd:N>
    <xsd:V>400232</xsd:V>
    <xsd:T>StlTextBox</xsd:T>
    <xsd:A />
  </xsd:Control>
</xsd:ArrayOfControl>');

DECLARE @targetTbl TABLE (page_id INT, entry_id INT, N VARCHAR(30), V VARCHAR(30), T VARCHAR(30), A VARCHAR(30));
-- DDL and sample data population, end

WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://tempuri.org/FormPersistance.xsd')
INSERT INTO @targetTbl (page_id, entry_id, N, V, T, A) 
SELECT page_id, entry_id, 
   c.value('(N/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(30)') AS N,
   c.value('(V/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(30)') AS V,
   c.value('(T/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(30)') AS T,
   c.value('(A/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(30)') AS A
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY page_xml.nodes('/ArrayOfControl/Control') AS t(c);

-- test
SELECT * FROM @targetTbl;
```

**Output**

```
+---------+----------+--------------------+--------+----------------------+------+
| page_id | entry_id |         N          |   V    |          T           |  A   |
+---------+----------+--------------------+--------+----------------------+------+
|    2219 |     1996 | pg1_UIObject1      | NULL   | StlAnnotationControl | NULL |
|    2219 |     1996 | pg1_TabItem1Panel1 | NULL   | StlCanvas            | NULL |
|    2219 |     1996 | pg1_txtPrefix      | MS     | StlTextBox           | NULL |
|    2219 |     1996 | pg1_txtSurname     | Joey   | StlTextBox           | NULL |
|    2219 |     1996 | pg1_txtNO          | 400232 | StlTextBox           | NULL |
+---------+----------+--------------------+--------+----------------------+------+
```

Comment: How should i read the column XML data into new table for each element as column

Comment: @Ravi1001, I updated the answer. Check it out.

Comment: ,how can i reference the column instead of refrencing the raw values. Like instead of "<xsd:ArrayofControl xmlns:xsd="http://tempuri.org/FormPersistance.xsd">
    <xsd:Control>
        <xsd:N>First element</xsd:N>
        <xsd:V>2nd element</xsd:V>
        <xsd:T>3rd element</xsd:T>
        <xsd:A>4th element</xsd:A>
    </xsd:Control>
    <xsd:Control>
        <xsd:N>First element again</xsd:N>
        <xsd:V>2nd element repeat</xsd:V>
        <xsd:T>3rd element repeat</xsd:T>
        <xsd:A>4th element repeat</xsd:A>
    </xsd:Control>
</xsd:ArrayofControl>"

Comment: @Ravi1001. I don't understand what you are referring to. While asking a question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example ##1-4. Not images.

Comment: what i meant was instead of refering to couple of elements from XML, how can i pass the whole row for the xml column. e.g. the first row in the screenshot. Apologies for not phrasing the question properly previously

Comment: @Ravi1001, just edit your original question, and provide ##1-4, i.e. a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Ravi1001, I updated the answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to add the default namespace
- If you want each `Control` node as a separate row, you need to break it out with `.nodes`

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://tempuri.org/FormPersistance.xsd')
SELECT e.page_id, e.entry_id, 
   x.Control.value('N[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS Col,
   x.Control.value('V[1]', 'varchar(250)') AS Col1,
   x.Control.value('T[1]', 'varchar(250)') AS Col2,
   x.Control.value('A[1]', 'varchar(250)') AS Col3
FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[Form] e
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CAST(e.page_xml as xml))) AS v(Casted)
CROSS APPLY v.Casted.nodes('/ArrayOfControl/Control') AS x(Control)
```

Comment: its complaining that "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'."

Comment: the query is running for very long time , even for top 10 records. there is no result. I had to kill the query

Comment: It works. Problem was with CROSS APPLY v.Casted.nodes('/ArrayofControl/Control') AS x(Control) where it should have been CROSS APPLY v.Casted.nodes('/ArrayOfControl/Control') AS x(Control). Thanks a lot